# Add active class to menu (without li) and based on url

Tags: jquery, css, class, menu

probably this topic is discussed many times but i can't find a working solution for my case.

I have this menu structure (the hrefs are in php: home.php but i use .htaccess to short them):

```
<div class="menu-submenu" id="menu_items">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="home" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Home</div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="home_1" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Home 1</div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="home_2" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Home 2</div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="home_3" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Home 3</div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="home_4" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Home 4</div></a>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr-multicolor">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="...etc" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Other</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and based on the url (ex: localhost/project/home) **the menu to be active must have the class active added on the generic div that contains the specific menu**.

Here how it must be:

```
<div class="menu-submenu" id="menu_items">
    <div class="menu-item **active**">
        <a href="home" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Home</div></a>
    </div>
```

I have tried to use a lot of jQuery but till now (probably my fault) none of them is working.
This one in particular, for unknown reasons return always false on the IF statement, even the strings are equal:

```
$(function () {
   var current = location.pathname.toLocaleLowerCase();
   $('.menu-submenu a').each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var href = $this.attr('href');
      console.log(href);
      href = href.replace(/\?.*/, "").toLocaleLowerCase();
      // if the current path is equal to the link name, should apply the active class
      // testing it via console log and also with alert, 
      // the strings are equal and also i tried using === on the IF statement
      if (href == current) {
          alert("ok");
          $this.addClass('active');
      } else {
               alert("ko");
            }
        })
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Ok, i got it solved**, apparently the class was added to the

```
<a class="menu-link active">
```

but it must be added to the closest div.

Here is how the final jQuery looks and work.

```
$(function () {
    var CurrentUrl= document.URL;
    var CurrentUrlEnd = CurrentUrl.split('/').filter(Boolean).pop();
    $('.menu-submenu a').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var href = $this.attr('href');
        //console.log(href);
        href = href.replace(/\?.*/, "").toLocaleLowerCase();
        // if the current path is equal to this link, make it active
        if (href == CurrentUrlEnd) {
            //alert(href+"--ok--"+CurrentUrlEnd);
            $this.closest('.menu-item').addClass('active');
        } else {
            alert(href+"--ko--"+CurrentUrlEnd);
        }
    })
})
```

Hopefully someone will find it useful.

Comment: Suspect `current` does not contain the String you anticipate. When to you get when you add `console.log(href, current);` to your script before your IF statement?

Comment: Yes, the console prints out the value before the alert called inside the IF and they are exactly the same.

Comment: Can you post that result here someplace. Since you are using `==` the two strings must match for it to be `true`

Comment: hi #Twisty, using == or === doesn't change the result on my side. The issue was, as i mentioned above, the parent div that contains the href menu. I was assigning the "active" attribute directly on the href but it have to be assigned to the div container.